Font appears blurry - can anyone help please (LG Monitor with Mac M1)
I recently bought a new monitor, I'll admit I don't know much about monitors, so any help you can give would be appreciated.
Monitor details:
https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/fhd-qhd/32mr50c-b/
LG  32MR50C-B 31.5" Full HD Curved Monitor

Resolution: 1920 x 1080
Aspect Ratio:  16:9
Refresh Rate (Max.): [Hz]100
Response Time: 5ms (GtG at Faster)

Laptop details:
MacBook Pro 13" M1 2020

Chip: Apple M1
Memory: 8GB
OS: Sonoma 14.5

Connection details: Mac has USB-C only, so I have a USB-C to HDMI adapter (this one to be precise)

You can see from the screenshot above that the fonts aren't appearing very crisp, I've split the screen to show the LG page with text, and the right side of a the screen is a random image - the image seems fine. The overlay on the right is one of the tools I have tried which shows what the setting is currently at.
Things I've tried:

Tried setting the settings in Mac System Settings to different resolutions, it's currently set at 1920 x 1080 (default) because nothing else seemed to be any good. Refresh rate is set to 100HZ and the colour profile is LG HDR 4K. (Screenshot below)
Installed a programme called BetterDisplay (I'll be honest, I'm not sure what I'm clicking but I've tried changing things)
Tried changing the antialiasing setting via terminal (From this guide) - tried 1 2 3 and 0
Reset the monitor to factory settings.
Tried a different HDMI cable.
Bought a new USB-C to HDMI adapter and it made no difference.


Can anyone tell me something else to try? Or did I just buy a rubbish monitor and I am going to have to suck it up? :(

Welcome to Ask Different.  Unfortunately, the pixels per inch for that display is evaluated by many people as inadequate for a sharp rendering. Here is another  thread that may help explain better than I can make in the comments section. Your research and documentation are commendable, I can’t find fault in your analysis. Are these helpful?

@bmike thank you. It wasn't the news I wanted but it does stop me in my endless mission to fix something that isn't broken. :( sad times indeed. (p.s. anyone want to buy a rubbish monitor from me?) :)

You've got pixels as big as dinner plates. Most 1080p displays are 24". Yours is 32".  See my answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/474306/which-external-monitor-to-choose-for-macbook?noredirect=1&lq=1

Thanks @benwiggy sad news, but I've learnt something about bad monitors now that is a valuable lesson.

It might make a great status board for someone to mount on a wall or play vintage videos or emulated games. Long live iTunes visualizer, minesweeper and solitaire !

Also, please put up an answer so you can check your problem is solved. Even if you link to the post that helped you most we can close this and your words will help others search for their issue and learn as they choose their next display.

@bmike sorry I have been on hols, how do I mark as answered?

Hi! https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer
